# Android HTTP connection issues

Tags: android, httpconnection, androidhttpclient

I have an issue while trying to uddate a listview inside my app, the app connects to my apache server and obtains the data through json, is working great with the `MainActivity` but when trying to connect in another activity using an `AsyncTask` and sometimes it works and sometimes don't.

The weird thing is that it appears to work better with 3G than WiFi.

I'm using the `httpclient-4.3.1.jar, httpcore-4.3.jar and httpmime-4.3.1.jar`

```
04-21 19:30:36.252: E/log_tag(10753): Error in http connection org.apache.http.conn.ConnectTimeoutException: Connect to /50.63.76.136:80 timed out
04-21 19:30:36.252: E/log_tag(10753): Error converting result java.lang.NullPointerException
04-21 19:30:36.252: E/log_tag(10753): Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: End of input at character 0 of
```

Appreciate any help

Comment: Have you confirmed that this isn't just an issue with the webserver?

Comment: My webserver is godaddy and works ok in browser and with 3G, the problem is with Wi-Fi

Comment: Then I would suspect that the internet connection provided via the WiFi connection is to blame

Comment: I suspected that too, but my coworkers installed the app and used their own wifis and had that issue too.